# Add bytestream into request body

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi

I have the code:

```
with open('thesis.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    filename = f.read()
```

I am trying to add the bytes into the request to Docusign as specified here: [Very basic stuff - how do I send a document to docusign via REST API? I only see <document bytes go here...> everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850209/very-basic-stuff-how-do-i-send-a-document-to-docusign-via-rest-api-i-only-see)

"DO NOT convert the byte stream to String before adding it to the DocuSign request -- the byte stream should be written directly into the request."

```
    def makeBody(file_stream, envelopeDef):
    body = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" + \
            "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" + \
            "Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n" + \
            "\r\n" + \
            envelopeDef + "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" + \
            "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n" + \
            "Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"thesis.pdf\"; documentId=1\r\n" + \
            "\r\n" + \
            file_stream + "\r\n" + \
            "--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n"
    return body
```

as specified at: http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument

However, the bytes class cannot be implicitly converted to a string. So how do I write the byte stream directly into the request?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for Docusign, the solution was to send everything in bytes. There was no particular Python specific solution for writing bytes with strings with conversion.

See [Create Docusign envelope with REST API using document bytes: "cannot convert"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813501/create-docusign-envelope-with-rest-api-using-document-bytes-cannot-convert)